# Sub-Field inside a Field in ZOHO CRM

Tags: crm, zoho

**how can create Sub-Field inside a Field to using custom fields?**

I want to create Sub-Field inside a Field such as Name field with Prefix Salutation.

**Following figure for your understanding...**
[image]

It is possible OR not?

If any one have solution of this question then tell me.